# Admob test ad working but not real ad

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I added everything to android application as per the instructions from the admob website. On both the emulator and phone i tested my app. The test ads were displaying properly. i generated a signed apk and still it is showing the test ads. what should i do?
here my code:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

in MainActivity:

```
 MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-9815982880222619/9339487889");

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Please help me!

Comment: It will take time to give real ads after configuring it on AdMob console  .
Please wait for some time and then try again.

Comment: It been about a month now. one of my other apps made at the same time is displaying real ads now

Comment: one month is quite long. you try to create a new ad banner again? also  you might want to email admob regarding this. your codes looks fine.

Comment: share your app logs

Comment: what is the error? see logs it will say error code 0,1 ,2 etc